# Sending multiple files including images to the client at once with XHR

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload

I'm currently trying to send multiple files including images in one request to the HTML client. The server language is unimportant because the client side is the problem.

For example, we have 2 pictures and 2 files with text contents. Now I encode them in base64, store them in an array and serialize it and send it to the client. This is no problem for text files, but what about pictures?

Somehow I don't see how I could possibly show them in HTML. Decoding them from base64 is no problem, but in order to show them in HTML in an image tag, I do need to store them in a file. A possible solution would be to pass it to flash or something but then I can just send it directly since I would have to load flash code which brings me back to my original problem...

Somehow I don't see a solution here yet. I've been using this process for a long time to combine javascript, css and other data that is requested to minimize the amount of separate requests and I recently came to me that it would further improve the performance if I could include images, too.

Comment: Base64 is fatter than binary. This does not improve performance.

Comment: This prevents images from being cached on the browsers. This does not improve performance either.

Comment: HTML5 LocalStorage solves that problem.